# SQL Select sum and group by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I am trying to get a list of all music of the same `music_id` to have the SUM of price and that it was recorded on the same day

Expected output:

```
 music_id  | name | price | created          
-----------+--------------+------------------------
 1222      | blue | 333   | 2015-07-07
 2222      | red  | 45    | 2016-07-07
 1222      | blue | 111   | 2017-07-07
```

I have a table that looks like this 'music'

```
 music_id  | name | price | created_at           
-----------+--------------+------------------------
 1222      | blue | 111   | 2015-07-07 22:42:39
 2222      | red  | 22.5  | 2016-07-07 22:42:39
 1222      | blue | 111   | 2017-07-07 22:42:39
 1222      | blue | 111   | 2015-07-07 11:42:39
 2222      | red  | 22.5  | 2016-07-07 11:42:39
 1222      | blue | 111   | 2015-07-07 11:42:39
```

this is my query:

```
SELECT music_id, name, SUM(price), TO_DATE(cast(created_at AS text), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS created FROM music GROUP BY music_id, created;
```

but I will get an error,

```
ERROR:  column "music.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate function
```

Comment: You would also need to include `TO_DATE(cast(created_at AS text), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS created` in the `SELECT` clause. Otherwise, you won't know which record in the output belongs to which date.

Comment: Questions like this one *need* to disclose Postgres version and table definition (showing data types and constraints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select must include your grouping column. Also, you can refer to column position in `group by` if you are using `postgres`

```
SELECT music_id, name, TO_DATE(cast(created_at AS text), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as created, SUM(price) 
FROM music 
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: @Kal you simply add name column and expand `group by` column. See edit.

Comment: how can I just group by `music_id` so I get the sum of `price` of a specific `music_id`?

Comment: @Kal `select music_id, sum(price) from music group by 1`. The idea here is to select columns of interest and group by columns of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It's cheaper to group by the `date` instead of its text representation:

```
SELECT music_id, name, SUM(price) AS created, created_at::date AS created
FROM   music
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 4;
```

*'YYYY-MM-DD'* is the default ISO format for dates anyway. You can still force any desired format with `to_char()` *after* the cast to `date`: `to_char(created_at::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` - the cast only to be in sync with `GROUP BY` where you replace the positional reference `4` with `created_at::date`.

In a normalized DB schema, you would not include the functionally dependent value `name` in this table, just `music_id` (which would be a foreign key to another table with all attributes).

The query would then just group by ID and day and fetch more attributes form the other table in another join *after* that ...